# Convert string into datetime timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a string `'201502190759'`. This represents 2015/02/19 at 7:59.

Is there a method within the python library that can convert `'201502190759'` into a `datetime` object or timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) will do it.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strptime('201502190759', '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
2015-02-19 07:59:00
```

The docs on the format modifiers are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).